# Maven couldn't installed correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The operation cannot be completed. See the details.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.6.1.20150625-2338)
>       Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.0.20150526-2032 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.0.20150526-2032) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.osgi 3.10.0' but it could not be found
>       Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.1.20150625-2338) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.osgi 3.10.0' but it could not be found
>       Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.6.1.20150625-2338)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.6.0,1.7.0)
>       Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.6.1.20150625-2338)
>       To: org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui [1.6.1.20150625-2338]

Comment: After facing the same error, I found that the current version of m2e was well ahead of my version of eclipse and I had to settle for a lesser version of m2e to avoid this error.  So for me, I would need to get a more recent version of eclipse if I want to make use of the current release.  Unchecking the box in eclipse which hides previous versions certainly is your friend in this case.

Answer (score 19):

Can you try running `Eclipse` as Admin and try this again?. Let me know how that goes.

what is the update url are you using, is this it **m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e** ?

Edit:

There are incompltibilities with different vertions of Eclipse and plugins,

I suggest you to use the update site

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.0

OR

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

The best bet is the release version, But if you are still getting the issue, try the milestone 1.

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake You do not need to have maven as your environment variable to work with m2e plugin in eclipse. Did you try my answer?

Comment: Can you try installing it through market place, What is the eclipse version?

Comment: still the same issue i tried it in that way as well 
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Comment: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.0 working
release version still issue arise

Comment: If the milestone is working then you have resolved your issue, You should read the answer careful next time. That is the reason I gave you several options

Comment: In my case, this was exactly the issue @NaveenDissanayake said. I changed the directory from /releases to /milestones/1.0 and it worked. So weird error.

Comment: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.0 worked for me.  the other link gave me the error